# $D$ is not open at $Y$, as $D$ is not open at $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let    $D=\{x\hspace{0.2cm}|\hspace{0.2cm} \frac{1}{2}\le|x|\le 1\}=\left[-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right]\cup \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]$, $Y=[-1,1]$

- $D$ is not open at $\mathbb{R}$, as there is no $\epsilon>0$ such as $B(-1,\epsilon)\subset D$, $B\left(-\frac{1}{2},\epsilon\right)\subset D$, $B\left(\frac{1}{2},\epsilon\right)\subset D$ and $B(1,\epsilon)\subset D$.
- $D$ is not open at $Y$, as $D$ is not open at $\mathbb{R}$.

Is that correct? Obs: Usual topology of the straight and $Y$ induced topology

Comment: What is Y here?

Comment: The first statement is correct although it should be $D$ instead of $0$ at the end. For the second statement, what is $Y$?

Comment: $Y=[-1,1]$ that's it here

Comment: How is the topology defined here?

Comment: Usual topology of the straight and $Y$ induced topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, $D$ is not open in $Y$ because there is no $\varepsilon > 0$ such that:
$$B\left(\frac 12, \varepsilon\right)\cap Y\subset D$$
However, *your* reasoning is faulty. For $D\subset Y\subset X$, the implication
$$D\text{ not open in } X\Rightarrow D\text{ not open in } Y$$
is **not** always true. For example, in your situation, $D$ is not open in $\mathbb R$, but $D$ is open in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can argue that $D = \overline D$, where $\overline D$ stands for the closure of $D$.

Comment: Sets are not doors: "closed" doesn't mean "not open". You need to additionally establish that fact in this case.